# How to mirror a VTK 3D mesh saved on a .vtp file?

Tags: mesh, vtk, paraview

I'm trying to spatially mirror (along the 'X' direction) geometry data in a couple of .vtp files, and currently facing an issue in Paraview. I am able to use the Reflection filter to achieve what I want, but for some reason I am unable to export back it to a .vtp file. Apparently the output of the filter is of type UnstructuredView, while the original dataset is in Geometry (PolyData).

I could not find any additional filter that will convert the point dataset to some type whose geometry I can export as .vtp. Is there a quick and clean way to achieve this, or am I completely off the mark, and will need to use the C++/Python API to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Transform` filter with a scale of `-1` on the axis you want.

Note that you can transform an Unstructured Grid into a Polydata with the `Extract Surface` filter, as the main difference between both dataset is that polydata is only 2D cells whereas Unstructured is 3D.